# WCF Service Operation doesnt start until i try to access it from client

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a wcf service (wsDualHttpBinding)  i changed it from BasicBinding to wsDualHttpBinding in order to support events , i implemented the callback contract and everything here is the attribute on my service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract(
    SessionMode = SessionMode.Required,
    CallbackContract = typeof(IServiceCallBack))]
```

now problem is : when i start the service it runs and everything is ok except its operation doesnt get started ! , now if i opened the client and try to call any method in the service it gets started and the operations gets started although the method i called has nothing to do with the operations at all.

also it used to work normaly before i change wsDualHttpBinding.

it looks like the service doesn't get instantiated untill a session open with the client.

the WCF service is hosted in a console application.

I have a list of ports to open if their auto-start set to true , in the constructor of the WCF service i get the ports from the database and check if any is auto-start and i open it , the wcf service expose features like adding new ports and removing ports and editing etc etc

any way to fix that ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: WCF operation must be consumed by something, that's the whole point.. so I'm not sure what you're asking here. To have something executing automatically write windows application and have it Scheduled, or even better Windows Service that starts automatically.

Comment: its a windows service which does operations and open ports for listening and a wcf over it which administrate the windows service.

Comment: Still not much sense. How exactly you expect the operation to "get started"? What should start it?

Comment: I have a list of ports to open if thier autostart set to true , in the constructor of the WCF service i get the ports from the database and check if any is autostart and i open it , the wcf service expose features like adding new ports and removing ports and editing etc etc

Comment: its obvious that the service is running On-Demand now just like if im hosting it on IIS although im hosting it in a console application i dont know why this is happening , also be aware it used to work when it used basichttpbinding but now that i changed it to dual it stoped working.

Comment: I'm still in the dark, sorry.. what you mean "it used to work"? The operation executed all by itself?

Comment: yes Shadow , it used to execute by it self once i start the host-service , which means the WCF used get instantiated once the service host get started.

Comment: can you provide the code that you use to start the ServiceHost(s)?

Answer (score 2):

WCF services running in IIS are not started until they are called. If you are running the latest (currently v7.5) version of IIS, then you can use the AppFabric auto-start feature, described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677260.aspx) and demonstrated [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paolos/archive/2010/10/30/how-using-appfabric-auto-start-feature-to-avoid-warm-up-delays-for-iis-hosted-wcf-receive-locations.aspx).

Comment: im hosting it in a console application !

Comment: since you're hosting it in a console application, can you please provide the code that you use to start the ServiceHost(s)?

Comment: var _ReceiverHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Controller));
_ReceiverHost.Open();

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same kind of thing to administer a background application.
Make sure your host can still instantiate your service. If you changed the binding name, maybe your host can no longer find it.